# How Comparing Dates in HQL?

Tags: hibernate, hql

i would like to compare two dates in HQL Query. I have something like:

```
from TeamPlayer as tp where  tp.team = :team and tp.playerStartDate < season.seasonStart;
```

Could any one help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @user2436180 did u mean about overlapping?

Comment: @gjman2: i want to compare dates to know if one date is greater than other one, that's what i meant

Comment: btw how about ur HQL? it works or not

Comment: Your query extracts all TeamPlayer where date od payerStartDate is lower than seasonStart. IHMO, that works fine. If you want another result please add comment to your question.

Comment: @JoeTaras: My problem that query renders always the same list even there is some players that startDate don't match with this criteria

Comment: @NiÑo: Try to use named parameter instead session.sessionStart and then change it as :team parameter. Tell me if it's OK.

Comment: @JoeTaras: Brilliant !! thank you so much, i did like you said and it works correctly now. Thanks again

Comment: @NiÑo: OK, have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer after comments:

The issue was:

```
from TeamPlayer as tp
where  tp.team = :team
and tp.playerStartDate < season.seasonStart;
```

The result user wants: get all team players of specified team with playerStartDate is lower than seasonStart.

I've adviced to apply a named parameter instead season.seasonStart because that value in that query are not valued properly and because is a constant and I use always named parameter to map constant in query.

In this way the result is OK.

Comment: @NiÑo: ;) At the next